# Markov Chain Reach One State for the first time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Here's my transition matrix with state $\{1,2,3,4\}$:

\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 1/3 & 0 &1/3\\
1/4 & 1/4 & 1/4 &1/4\\
0 & 0& 1/2 &1/2\\
0 &0 &1/2 &1/2
\end{bmatrix}

I try to answer the following questions: If the Markov process starts from 2, what is the expected time that it visits state 3 or 4 in the first time? Moreover, what is the expected time that it visits the state 3 seconds time?

If I let $u_i$ be the expected time that it visits state 3 or 4 in the first time starting from i. Then from
$$
u_1=1+(1/3)u_2+(1/3)u_3, u_2=1+(1/4)u_1+(1/4)u_3+(1/4)u_4, u_3=u_4=0
$$
we can solve $u_2$ for the first part.

But what is the expected time that it visits the state 3 seconds time? General, how about visiting the state 3 for fourth time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** If a walk is started at 2, for it to visit 3 a second time, it must:

- travel from 2 to 3, then
- travel from 3 to 3 again.

Since expectation is linear, the time you want is the sum of the expectations of those two events, which you can find by methods like what you outlined in your question.

---

**EDIT** to clarify based on your comments: I think you're still making this much too complicated.

First, a correction to your question: you outlined a solution to find $u_2$  but I think your system of equations had some mistakes. It should have been:

\begin{align*}
  u_1 &= 1 + \color{red}{\frac 1 3 u_1} + \frac 1 3 u_2 + \frac 1 3 u_4 \\
  u_2 &= 1 + \frac 1 4 u_1 + \color{red}{\frac 1 4 u_2} + \frac 1 4 u_3 + \color{red}{\frac 1 4 u_4} \\
u_3 & = 0 \\
u_4 & = 0
\end{align*}

The intuition for why these relationships is valid is that from each state, you first take a single step, then weight the expected time to go from your first-step destination to 3 by the probability of each move. You can omit the $u_3$ and $u_4$ terms if you want since they're $0$, but the missing $u_1$ and $u_2$ terms will be important.

---

To find the expected time for the *second* visit somewhere, you'll need to solve some different systems of equations. If we take your example of starting the walk at 2 and computing its second visit to 3, we break that up into two occurrences; first, the walk must go from 2 to 3 a first time (taking however many steps it needs), then it must go from 3 to 3. You referenced a concern about "many cases" in your comments, but **there are no cases**; this is the only way to visit 3 twice.

To find the expected number of steps to go from 2 to 3, we set up a system very much like the one you outlined above:

\begin{align*}
  u_1 &= 1 + \frac 1 3 u_1 + \frac 1 3 u_2 + \frac 1 3 u_4 \\
  u_2 &= 1 + \frac 1 4 u_1 + \frac 1 4 u_2 + \frac 1 4 u_3 + \frac 1 4 u_4 \\
  u_3 &= 0 \\
  u_4 &= 1 + \frac 1 2 u_3 + \frac 1 2 u_4
\end{align*}
and note that these values of $u_1$ are different than the ones above. Solving for $u_2$ gives the first needed component.

For returning from 3 to 3, we need another system:

\begin{align*}
  u'_1 &= 1 + \frac 1 3 u'_1 + \frac 1 3 u'_2 + \frac 1 3 u'_4 \\
  u'_2 &= 1 + \frac 1 4 u'_1 + \frac 1 4 u'_2 + \frac 1 4 u'_3 + \frac 1 4 u_4' \\
  u'_3 &= \color{blue}{\frac 1 2 \cdot 1 + \frac 1 2 u'_4} \\
  u'_4 &= 1 + \frac 1 2 u'_3 + \frac 1 2 u'_4
\end{align*}

We had to adjust the $u_3$ line here so that we guarantee that the walk takes at least one step. The intuition for the blue line is that a walk started at 3 will either immediately return to 3 (in which case the excursion required just 1 move), or it will go to state 4. Note that since we only care about $u'_3$, the $u'_1$ and $u'_2$ lines are irrelevant.

Solving the first system for $u_2$ gives the expected number of moves for a walk started at 2 to visit 3. Solving the second system for $u_3'$ gives the expected number of moves for a walk started at 3 to return to 3. Adding these together gives the expected number of steps for a walk started at 2 to make its **second** visit to 3. Again, there are no cases to consider, because everything is baked into the existing expected values we computed.

Comment: Doing the calculation for the third time is no more difficult than doing it for the second. Don't take $u_i$ to be the expected steps to visit a state for the *second* time; have it be the expected steps to visit a state for the *first* time (always), then add several of these types of things together. For instance, if it takes 1.5 steps (on average) to go from 2 to 3, and 0.5 steps (on average) to go from 3 to 3, then it will take $1.5 + 0.5$ steps to make the second visit to 3 from 2, and $1.5 + 0.5 + 0.5$ for the third visit.

Comment: I am still confused. Can you list one example for $u_2$?

Comment: These cases are not a problem; you're overthinking it. I'm working on amending my answer.

Comment: No, there are not lots of cases. I am working on a response. Please be patient.

Comment: Do you understand the method I outlined in my revised post? It is trivial to generalize this method to your new question. Can you handle it from here?

Comment: Exactly! (And it would be the same $u'_3$ that you calculated in the previous step that you'd need to add, too!)

Comment: Correct! ${}{}{}{}$