# Which class is positive recurrent?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Here's my transition matrix with state $\{1,2,3,4\}$:

\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 1/3 & 0 &1/3\\
1/4 & 1/4 & 1/4 &1/4\\
0 & 0& 1/2 &1/2\\
0 &0 &1/2 &1/2
\end{bmatrix}

There will be two commutation class $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$. Ther are all irreducible. Which one is null recurrent and which one is positive recurrent? Or all transit?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery These two classes are both null recurrent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints that apply for any **finite-state** Markov Chain:

(1) Due to the pigeonhole principle, it is not possible for all states to be transient. At least one state *must* be visited infinitely often with a positive probability, and that state is recurrent.

(2) **Null** recurrence is **never** possible. Let $x$ be a recurrent state, and for any state $y$ in the same commuting class, define $f(y) := \mathbb P_y(T_x < k)$ where $T_x$ is the hitting time of $x$ and $k$ is the number of states in the chain. By the pigeonhole principle, $f(y) > 0$. Moreover, let $S$ represent the set of states in the same communicating class as $x$; then $c := \min_{y \in S} f(y)$ and $c > 0$ because there are a finite number of states. This implies a geometric bound on the return times of a walk started at $x$; after a walk takes one step away from $x$, it has a probability of at most $1 - c$ of not returning within the next $k$ steps, and a probability of at most $(1 - c)^2$ of not returning within the next $2k$ steps, and so on. Since this probability tends to $0$, the excursions are dominated by a geometric random variable and they have finite expectation.

(And just to re-emphasize the point: these comments only apply for finite-state Markov chains. Infinite-state Markov chains are much more complicated / interesting.)

Comment: So my answer is right? Since I find the equation $pi P=pi$ has no solution, these two classes are not positive recurrent.

Comment: No, your answer is impossible. Every finite state Markov chain has at least one recurrent state, and all recurrent states are positive recurrent. You should re-check your equation; there is indeed a nontrivial solution.

Comment: I see. So two classes are both positive recurrent?

Comment: No; one class is transient.

Comment: So $\{1,2\}$ is transient? Since 1>3, then it will never return?

Comment: Correct. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks! Can you see another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4401256/markov-chain-reach-one-state-for-the-first-time